# control behavior of jQuery tooltip

Tags: jquery

I'm looking for a very specific behaviour from a tooltip, which I can't seem to find out of the box.
My requirements are:
1. tooltip should appear when item is hovered over.
2. tooltip should disappear after item is hovered-out.
3. tooltip should remain visible when:  mouse is over the tooltip
   OR
4. tooltip should remain visible when a user clicks the item
(either option 3 or 4 is acceptable on its own).

the first two are trivial, of course, but the third is tricky-

- [cluetip](http://plugins.learningjquery.com/cluetip/demo/) has an option to leave the tooltip open until closed by the user, but that's not exactly what I want (I want the tooltip to remain open only if the user has clicked the item).

  - perhaps I could change cluetip's behaviour in runtime (i.e- defaultly the behaviour would be 'close normally', but when a user clicks the item - the cluetip behaviour would change to 'close by user')?
- [beautyTip](http://www.lullabot.com/files/bt/bt-latest/DEMO/index.html) has a variety of events to configure for show / hide, but I couldn't think of a combination I could use.

Any thoughts?
Thanks,
Jhonny

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This one remains active when you hover over it:

http://tutorialzine.com/2010/07/colortips-jquery-tooltip-plugin/

As does:

http://flowplayer.org/tools/demos/tooltip/index.html

Comment: +1 for the flowplayer one. I use it from time to time and it's awesome.

Comment: same as mingos. although by riffing through the forums of the flowplayer plugin it seems that it isn't maintained anymore, and might have issues with the new jQuery version (1.5). anybody knows anything about that?

Comment: ended up using the flowplayer one (jQuery tools), using the 'title' attribute of my objects. Thanks!